# Backup/Restore a city from SimCity 4

Tags: simcity-4

I want to take a backup of my city of SimCity 4.

In the directory `Documents\SimCity 4\Regions\` in `Libraries` (Windows 7), I have a directory with the name of my city. Do I need to include something else in the backup if I want to restore my city from a fresh installation of SimCity 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is where the SimCity 4 save games are kept.  To be on the safe side, I'd copy the whole SimCity4 directory from your Documents folder.  I believe they're organized by region, and then within the region the individual saved cities are located.

This [About.com article](http://compsimgames.about.com/cs/simcity4/ht/savecities.htm) mentions backing up this folder in order to back up your SimCity 4 saves, and I remember copying this folder before when I played SimCity 4.

Answer (score 0):

In order to restore / backup a *Region*, you'll need to backup either the `Documents\SimCity 4\Regions` folder, or one of the individual region's folders within the `Regions` folder. If you've used any plugins when creating your region, you should also backup the `Documents\SimCity 4\Plugins` folder.

One important thing to note though, is the distinction between regions and cities. A city is made up of a single tile, where as a region is made up of one or more city tiles. The reason why this distinction is important is because whilst it is possible to restore an entire region (meaning all its cities) simply by copying and pasting the region's folder from your backup, it is not possible to restore a single city tile within the region due to the way  Simcity 4 handles save games.

In other words, if you've accidentally flattened one of your cities or a city has become corrupted (perhaps due to bugs associated with using the "Save and..." options), the only way to restore that one, single city tile, is to restore the entire region from backup.